# unable to find r-package - BayNErd

Tags: r, spatial, cran, bayesian-networks, install.packages

According to this [article](http://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/5/11/5999), BayNeRD should have been implemented in R already. However I cannot find it at the list of [available CRAN packages](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html), neither anywhere on the internet.

Where can i find this package?

Comment: If it is not there, check with the author to get the best update

Comment: I agree with @akrun; however, the fact that the paper was published in 2013 and that you can't find anything on the web does not bode well...

Comment: The same people did mention this in 2017 paper.  So, it is a bit mystery

Comment: As far as I can see, they didn't say anywhere that they have released the package.